# JUnit4 + Eclipse "An internal error occurred during Launching"

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm trying to run JUnit4 test cases on Eclipse 3.4.2 but it's not even starting for me. I have the junit-4.7.jar in my build path and the test application.

Here is a simple example that illustrates my problem

```
package test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class UTest {    
    @Test
    public void test() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

This compiles fine

Then I do "Run JUnit Test case" from Eclipse and I get an error dialog with this message

```
"Launching UTest' has encountered a problem
An internal error occurred during: "Launching UTest".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What causes these NullPointerExceptions?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix this just by deleting the workspace and the Eclipse directory and starting over.

Comment: Did you re-import the project, or re-build in by manually dragging files? Sound like a lot of work that just avoids the problems, doesn't solve it.

Comment: Yes, you have to import to import all the files manually but your eclipse editor setting will be change.

Answer (score 32):

What worked for me after trying everything:

1. Go to help
2. Install New Software
3. Work with: Juno
4. Programming languages (expand it)
5. Install Java Development Tools
6. Restart

It works :)

Comment: The name of the package I had to install was *Eclipse Java Development Tools* rather than just *Java Development Tools*.

Comment: @Sam What will be the update url? I am already having Juno with ADT 23.0.2.

Comment: @devo The update site already comes with Eclipse itself. Just open up the drop-down menu and you'll find it.

Comment: This is the answer. Seems to be a problem with the ADB bundle which somehow didn't include the Java Development Tools. Nonsensical error all again in Eclipse.

Comment: Works on Mars too, even on an IDE that is based on Eclipse (Progress Development Studio; don't ask).

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

1. create another copy of the test class (CopyOfUTest.java)
2. run the copy to make sure it passes
3. go into Run > Run Configurations
4. under JUnit, find the run configurations for the original class and the copied class
5. right click and delete the configuration of the original class
6. rename the configuration of the copied class to the original configuration name
7. delete the copied class from the project

Comment: This didn't work for me; the scope of the problem seems beyond just the single test class.

Answer (score 3):

None of the given answers here worked for me, so I ended up just installing and using [InfiniTest](http://infinitest.github.io/) instead. It doesn't have this problem, and it also runs the tests automatically so I can focus on my work.

[image: Eclipse with Infinitest showing a red "tests failed" status message and the corresponding assertion error in the "Problems" tab]

Comment: You rock! This is the only thing that worked for me using ADT 23+!

Comment: @HughB Do you know why the normal JUnit4 not working here? Any fixes you got?

Comment: @devo, I don't know why this problem happens, but the fix in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26517489/238753) worked for me.

Comment: @devo - I eventually was able to get my Junit tests to run independently of Infinitest by going to Run Configurations, Classpath Tab, then remove Android 4.4.2 from Bootstrap Entries for the tests.

Comment: @HughB Thanks, I am also getting the tests by using the ``Infinitest``.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked in the Eclipse error log?  You can see it by opening the "Error Log" view.

http://help.eclipse.org/help32/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/views/error_log.htm

Comment: Couldn't find that view. Problems view is unrelated, this is an eclipse INTERNAL error, problems view just shows errors in the project.

Comment: I said the Errors view ... not the Problems view.

Comment: +1 Great, error log show the detail information of the error. You can fix it according to the error log.

Comment: *"I don't have an Errors view"* - you will find it in Window > Show View > General > Error Log.

Answer (score 2):

**This error In eclipse can be caused if you are also using the Android Development Kit plugins:**

```
"Launching UTest' has encountered a problem
    An internal error occurred during: "Launching UTest".
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can be caused if you are loading a normal Java project into an Eclipse instance with android ADT plugins installed and enabled.  In this situation, Eclipse looks for "Android" project files, and doesn't find any.  So it says: "NullPointerException".

So to fix it, re-download Eclipse without the ADT Plugin: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Then re-import your project fresh.  And the junit tests run without a problem.

Many people hate eclipse for it's enigmatic error messages.  It's like we are back in the 1950's punch card world, where there are no error messages.  The program just halts and undefined behavior occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me.

Eclipse
Version: 3.4.1
Build id: M20080911-1700

I right click on the .java file RunAs JUnit Test.  This would indicate the problem is caused by an Eclipse configuration problem, not a code problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks that solved my problem too.
The problem started when i removed an old simulator, and created a new one.
Fix: Like the OP says remove the workspace, make sure to keep the projects inside it :)
then import them back to eclipse
"Sound like a lot of work" ?
Took me less than half a minute !!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android and its associated plugins, then Android only supports JUnit 3.

I resolved the problem by selecting Test Runner as JUnit 3.

In my class, JUnit 4 is added in the build path->libraries.

Then to run the test file, go to: Run As -> Run Configurations then select the corresponding test.java file and select Test Runner accordingly(whether it is JUnit 3 or 4).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem but I am using Python. This is what I did to solve/avoid it:

1. Removed my .project file and the project from Eclipse.
2. Created the project again.
3. Everything was working.

The problem seemed to be in the .project file where there were some references to CDT Builder and were not there in the new .project file.