# Junit tests won't run in eclipse kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, junit

Junit works when compiling in command line on Linux but not in eclipse kepler.

I'm using maven, jboss and spring. When I run the program it says 'launching classname' has encountered a problem, an internal error occurred during: "Launching classname". 
Details: An internal error occurred during: "Launching classname", `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: Try [some of these](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1250505/2587435)

Comment: I'm trying the new workspace solution. and now my imports are broken; any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running maven, you can close out eclipse, open a command prompt and run:

```
mvn eclipse:clean
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

I tried this before posing this question with eclipse open in the background; make sure it is closed!
Also I deleted my workspace and restored said workspace but that's probably irrelevant. 
Sidenote: the solution posed by aryaxt didn't work for me. Hope it works for you!