# Can't add JUnit 4 library to the build path in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit4

I have some trouble with adding the JUnit 4 library to the build path (using Eclipse). 
I have these imports:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
```

This error occurs: "The import org.junit cannot be resolved". I already found out why it's saying that.

I've tried different ways to add the library, but I always get this error:
[image]

What is causing this? And how can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250505/junit4-eclipse-an-internal-error-occured-during-launching